# How to use cookies with php soap client?

Tags: c#, php, soap, binding, client

i am connecting to webservice using php.

```
 try {
    $client = new SoapClient("https://.....",array(
       'exceptions' => true
    ));

  } catch ( SoapFault $e ) { 
    echo 'sorry... our service is down';
  }
```

in c# it is working, while in binding for that is set allowCookies="true".

how and where should i add this allowCookies="true", if i want to use php soap client?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`SoapClient::__setCookie()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setcookie.php)

Comment: found this>   $client->__setCookie($name, $value);    what should i use for $name and for $value ?

Comment: My best guess would be to go with the documentation: `$name` for the name of the cookie, `$value` for the value (or null if you want to remove it)